# Allow site-specific answering notices for 101 rep users

Tags: feature-request, answers

When you try to answer a question on an SE site as a new user you'll be greeted by a notice like the following one:

[image]

These notices can be adapted for each site, this specific one is for Skeptics.

Most SE sites work pretty much the same, there isn't much to learn when you start out there if you are already familiar with the SE system. Some sites though have very different rules from other sites, I think this notice would be a good way to succinctly explain those differences to users coming from another SE site.

This notice is currently not shown to users with 101 rep due to the association bonus. I propose to show these users a very similar notice, but shortened to only the parts that are specific to each site.

So an experienced SE user answering their first question on Skeptics would get a short notice explaining that references are required for answers. Other sites could adapt the notices to their purposes.

Comment: Perhaps showing this notice should be based on the number of questions asked rather than reputation points.

Comment: @ValetTree I'm using the 101 rep as shorthand for users that havent posted anything on the site, but got the 100 rep from the association bonus. Implementing it not as a reputation-based filter would be better, but I don't know how difficult it would be